# antd input search component not getting blurred on blur()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, antd

I am using Search Input component of antd library. It comes with a call back function onSearch where we can catch the event target and can use global input functions like blur(), focus(). But that doesn't seem to work. If I attach any other event handler like onClick or onChange it worked. Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Input } from 'antd';

const Search = Input.Search;

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Search
      placeholder="input search text"
      onSearch={(value,e) => {
        console.log(e.target);
        e.target.blur();
        console.log(value)
        }}
      enterButton
      onChange={e => {
        console.log(e.target)
        e.target.blur()}}
    />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of `antd` refocusing it after the handler. You can use a `setTimeout` on the `blur` handler to have it blur correctly.

But using `event.target` would work only on enter key, you have to use a `ref` element on the input to have it work on the buttons.

```
<Search
  placeholder="input search text"
  onSearch={(value, e) => {
    const input = this.input.current;
    setTimeout(() => input.blur(), 0);
  }}
  enterButton
  ref={this.input}
/>
```

See an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vqrr80m085)

Comment: you mean to say that after the event handler gets called it refocuses it self. Why is it doing that ? Can you please explain this weird behaviour a little more....

Comment: @AirasYaqub I know this from logging the blur and focus events on the input element, on why they are doing it I'm not sure, will have to go through their source code to figure out